# $\left[ - \mathcal{L} \left\{ \dfrac{F(t)}{t} \right\} \right]_s^\infty$ to $\mathcal{L} \left\{ \dfrac{F(t)}{t} \right\}\bigg\vert_s$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

I'm currently studying the textbook *An Introduction to Laplace Transforms and Fourier Series*, second edition, by Phil Dyke. Chapter **2.2 Derivative Property of the Laplace Transform** gives the following theorem and proof:

> **Theorem 2.3** *If $\mathcal{L}(F(t)) = f(s)$ then $\mathcal{L}\left\{ \dfrac{F(t)}{t} \right\} = \int_s^\infty f(u) \ du$, assuming that $\mathcal{L}\left\{ \dfrac{F(t)}{t} \right\} \to 0$ as $s \to \infty$.*
>
> **Proof** Let $G(t)$ be the function $F(t)/t$, so that $F(t) = t G(t)$. Using the property
> $$\mathcal{L}\{ t G(t) \} = - \dfrac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}\{ G(t) \}$$
> we deduce that
> $$f(s) = \mathcal{L} \{ F(t) \} = - \dfrac{d}{ds} \mathcal{L} \left\{ \dfrac{F(t)}{t} \right\}.$$
> Integrating both sides of this with respect to $s$ from $s$ to $\infty$ gives
> $$\int_s^\infty f(u) \ du = \left[ - \mathcal{L} \left\{ \dfrac{F(t)}{t} \right\} \right]_s^\infty = \mathcal{L} \left\{ \dfrac{F(t)}{t} \right\}\bigg\vert_s = \mathcal{L} \left\{ \dfrac{F(t)}{t} \right\}$$
> since
> $$\mathcal{L} \left\{ \dfrac{F(t)}{t} \right\} \to 0 \ \ \ \text{as} \ \ \ s \to \infty$$
> which completes the proof.

I'm confused about this part:

> $$\int_s^\infty f(u) \ du = \left[ - \mathcal{L} \left\{ \dfrac{F(t)}{t} \right\} \right]_s^\infty = \mathcal{L} \left\{ \dfrac{F(t)}{t} \right\}\bigg\vert_s = \mathcal{L} \left\{ \dfrac{F(t)}{t} \right\}$$

How do we get from $\left[ - \mathcal{L} \left\{ \dfrac{F(t)}{t} \right\} \right]_s^\infty$ to $\mathcal{L} \left\{ \dfrac{F(t)}{t} \right\}\bigg\vert_s$, and then from $\mathcal{L} \left\{ \dfrac{F(t)}{t} \right\}\bigg\vert_s$ to $\mathcal{L} \left\{ \dfrac{F(t)}{t} \right\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like mostly a confusion about notation. The notation

$$\left[f(x)\right]_s^\infty$$

is shorthand for

$$\lim_{b\to\infty} f(b)-f(s)\ .$$

So

$$\left[- \mathcal{L} \left\{ \dfrac{F(t)}{t}\right\}\right]_s^{\infty} = -\lim_{b\to\infty}\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{F(t)}{t}\right\}\bigg\vert_b + \mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{F(t)}{t}\right\}\bigg\vert_s$$

Because of the assumption that the Laplace transform approaches $0$ as the input approaches $\infty$ the first term vanishes. The second is just the value of the Laplace transform of $\frac{F(t)}{t}$ evaluated at $s$. Both

$$\mathcal{L}\left.\left\{\frac{F(t)}{t}\right\}\right\vert_s$$

and

$$\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{F(t)}{t}\right\}$$

are ways to denote this. In the second case the dependence on $s$ has been suppressed.

Comment: I had to edit your answer because the original notation you were using was nonsensical.